# Php Getters and Setters

Tags: php, ооп, getter, setter

есть небольшая проблема с кодом. Можно ли как-то через цикл вывести все данные с бд в html при этом используя метод Getter. Например есть Класс Name

```
<?php   

class Name {  

    protected $id;   
    protected $first;   
    protected $second;   
    protected $third;    
    protected $fourth;   

    private $db;

    public function __construct(array $config = []){
        $this->db = new Database();   
        $this->id = $config['id'];   
        $this->first = $config['first'];
        $this->second = $config["second"];   
        $this->third = $config["third"];   
        $this->fourth = $config["fourth"];   
    }

    public function getProducts(string $fields, string $tablename){
        $this->db->query("SELECT $fields FROM $tablename");
        //Assign Result Set
        $result = $this->db->array();
        return $result;
    }

    public function getProduct(string $fields, string $tablename, string $id, string $param){
        $this->db->query("SELECT $fields FROM $tablename WHERE $id =  $param");
        //Assign Result Set
        $result = $this->db->array();
        return $result;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirst() {
        return $this->first;
    }

    public function getSecond() {
        return $this->second;
    }

    public function getThird() {
        return $this->third;
    }

    public function getFourth() {
        return $this->fourth;
    }
}
```

Мы можем вывести все данные с помощью функции getProducts и вернуть в виде массива. Потом присвоить массив объекту например $array или $single в случае определенных данных.

```
    $test = new Name();
$array = $test->getProducts('*', 'products');
$single = $test->getProduct('*', 'products', 'id', '15');
```

Например если я дам объекту массив `$result = new Name($data);`

```
$data = [
"name" => "ProductName",
"id" => "ProductID",
"sku" => "dasdas",
"price" => "Price",
"type" => "rwer"
```

];

Тогда я могу спокойно вывести данные с помощью методов Getter

```
<?php 
echo $result->getId() . '<br>';
echo $result->getFirst() . '<br>';
echo $result->getSecond() . '<br>';
echo $result->getThird() . '<br>';
echo $result->getFourth() . '<br>';
?>
```

Но если я присвою аргумент $array или $single Классу Name то получаю пустой output. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее Спасибо.

Comment: я бы сначала разобрался с SQL инъекциями, а потому же игрался с геттерами...

Comment: а по поводу геттеров - сначала надо выкинуть чудовищный класс db

Comment: по крайней мере разделить датасет и сущности в отдельные классы

Comment: @teran да мне кажется можно AR оставить. Вот - елоквент как-то же живет с этим, таская все причиндалы вместе с данными. Но по-хорошему-то да, надо

Comment: Это просто работа на локальном сервере, sql инъекции сейчас не в приоритете

Comment: **А когда они в приоритете будут?** Когда все будет готово и придется весь код переписывать? И речь вообще не об этом кривом коде, а о том, с чем тебе надо разобраться. Что учить. сначала учимся работать с БД, потом пробуем колупать ООП

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо за совет :)

Answer (score -1):

Я предлагаю выкинуть класс DB, и использовать вместо него оригинальный PDO.

```
public function __construct(PDO $db){
    $this->db = $db;   
}
```

и сделать метод

```
public function getBySQL($sql, $params = []) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, self::class);
}
```

который вернет тебе массив маленьких объектиков того же класса

```
$array = $test->getBySQL('SELECT * FROM products');
```

а получение единичного экземпляра по айди переписать так

```
public function getById($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` WHERE id=?";
    $ret = $this->getBySQL($sql, $id);
    return reset($ret);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я использую абстрактный класс или так называемый "Маппер" чтобы остальные классы могли унаследовать его функционал.

Comment: Но у меня была проблема именно с геттерами, я просто не понимал как с помощью геттера получить данные с бд. Сколько не искал инфо про геттеры и сеттеры везде были примеры просто со строками в аргументах.

Comment: Ну разумеется. Невозможно найти информацию, которой нет. Геттеры и сеттеры к БД ВООБЩЕ никакого отношения не имеют. Поэтому ты ничего и не найдешь

Comment: Понятно. В тех. задание было это описано. Also, mysql logic should be handled by object with properties instead of direct column values. Please use setters and getters for achieving this.Не знаю как у вас с английским, могу перевести если надо :)

Comment: Я не знаю как ты переводил, но здесь нигде не написано, что данные из бд надо получать с помощью геттера.

Comment: Последний вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста паттерны которые можно использовать здесь ?

Comment: Это не вопрос. На него нельзя дать ответ. То что написано по-английски, называется ActiveRecord, когда класс содержит и данные, и методы работы с ними